# How do I modify this query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, regex

```
SELECT title, title REGEXP 'apple' as is_fruit FROM mytable;
```

TO:

```
SELECT title, title REGEXP 'apple' or orange...or grapes...as is_fruit...
```

Basically, how do I do an "OR" for REGEXP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT title, title REGEXP '(apple|orange|...)' as is_fruit FROM mytable;
```